# Windows 8 Software Update in Background?

Tags: windows-8, windows-update, modern-ui

When I start the Windows Update in the Metro UI and then exit to the Desktop, is the Update then still in progress?

Is there a possiblity to see running metro applications in the background?

Comment: Windows Update isn't a Metro Application thus it can run in the background.  Of course other Metro application can be ran in the background but they work slightly different then traditional process being ran in the background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I start the Windows Update in the Metro UI and then exit to the Desktop, is the Update then still in progress?

Windows Update is a *service* so once you command it to do something it will proceed in doing so regardless in which way you commanded it to run and in which way you close the UI you have used.

> Is there a possiblity to see running metro applications in the background?

Not entirely sure what you mean by this, but I'll attempt to first explain what happens when a Metro application goes into the background: **It suspends**; so, it's no longer actively running most of the time unless the application were to have a background task (!= service) which will most likely keep running or might run on a scheduled basic.

So, while you can find the application in the Task Manager (to see if it does something) as well as in tools like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) (from SysInternals, lets you see and filter all the I/O events happening on a system) it will probably not do that much in general when it is in the background. It should also be noted that there's only a certain limit of background Metro tasks that can keep running as to not consume much memory, after opening a few the oldest used ones will save their state and close.

But let's say you want to monitor a Metro app while it's running and you want to keep it running, you can do this by placing the app on the side of your screen such that it shows next to your desktop.

Comment: Oh Metro is more or less single application? Placing the app on the side of your screen, what do you meen by that?

Comment: @FiveO: For instance, drag the top of the Metro application to the left side of your screen. It will make it stick in the left side of the screen to make it a column and you will be able to use the other part (after pressing the windows key?) for another application or your desktop.

Comment: Oh nice - works even with multiple monitors. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Tom Wijsman stated, Windows Update is a *service*, not an *app*, and will continue running in the background, regardless of what other programs or apps, desktop or Windows Runtime, you're running.

Windows Update uses the [Background Intelligent Transfer Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_Intelligent_Transfer_Service), so it should be downloading the update(s) as you work, throttling as needed to avoid interfering with your Internet connection, while taking advantage of unused bandwidth.